# Heroku local command returns error: This program requires Apache 2.4.10

Tags: php, apache, heroku

I am new to heroku and I am trying to deploy a php site that was written about 2 years ago. When I run `heroku local` I get the following error and I am not sure how to fix it:

`This program requires Apache 2.4.10 or newer with mod_proxy and mod_proxy_fcgi enabled; check your 'httpd' command.`

My Procfile:
`web: $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2`

My composer.json:

`{
    "name": "simple-mvc-framework/framework",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "Framework for PHP 5.4+",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/simple-mvc-framework/framework",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "David Carr",
            "email": "dave@daveismyname.com",
            "homepage": "http://daveismyname.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/whatitiscreative/contentful-sdk"
        },
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/wellingguzman/zend-db"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "3.*",
        "mandrill/mandrill": "1.0.*",
        "mixpanel/mixpanel-php" : "2.*",
        "contentful/contentful": "@beta",
        "gamegos/jwt": "~0.1",
        "zendframework/zend-eventmanager": "^3.0",
        "zendframework/zend-servicemanager": "^3.1",
        "zendframework/zend-hydrator": "^2.2",
        "directus/sdk": "0.1.*",
        "algolia/algoliasearch-client-php": "^1.18",
        "php-console/php-console": "^3.1@dev"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"": "app/"},
        "files": ["app/files/password.php"]
    },
}`

Do I need to add apache as a requirement in my composer file?

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58024812/heroku-local-with-php-on-mac-os-x) where I've tried to answer this question.